# How to call the appropriate constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Why am I not able to call the appropriate constructor for the `Geometry` object?

```
class Geometry {
private:
  float fRadius;
  int iSegments;
  float fWidth;
  float fLenght;
  std::string stdstrType;
  bool bValid;

public:
  Geometry() {
    // Set data Elements
    qDebug() << "Constructor 1 is called";
  }

  Geometry(float Radius, int Segments, float Width, float Length,
    std::string strType, bool bValue) {
    // Set data Elements
    qDebug() << "Constructor 2 is called";
  }

  Geometry(const Geometry & g) {
    // Set data Elements
    qDebug() << "Constructor 3 is called";
  }
}
```

I use this class as a data variable in another class.

```
class Container {
private:
  std::string stdstrContainerName;
  std::string stdstrPluginType;
  Geometry Geom;

public:
  Container();
  Container(std::string, std::string, Geometry geometry);
};

Container::Container() {
  stdstrContainerName = "Group";
  stdstrPluginType = "Geometry";
}

Container::Container(std::string strName, std::string strType,
  Geometry geometry) {
  stdstrContainerName = stdstrContainerName;
  stdstrPluginType = stdstrPluginType;
  Geom = geometry;
}
```

When I try to set a `Geometry` object in the container, even though I have given all the parameters for constructor 2 to be called, constructor 1 is called.

```
geometry(0.3, 32, 0.0, 0.0, "SPHERE", true);
Container cont("Sphere", "SPHERE", geometry);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding your use case, here's what each line calls:

```cpp
Geometry geometry(0.3, 32, 0.0, 0.0, "SPHERE", true);    // Geometry constructor 2    
Container cont("Sphere", "SPHERE", geometry);            // Container constructor 2, Geometry constructors 3 & 1
```

Here, the constructor for `Geometry` is actually called *outside* the constructor of `Container`. But Geometry constructor 3 and 1 are also being called... why?

Why indeed. Since the constructor for `Container` takes a `Geometry` parameter by value, the `geometry` object passed will be copied (hence, the copy constructor is called). Next, Geometry constructor 1, aka the *default constructor* is actually called in the constructor of `Container`. Afterwards, copy-assignment, another implicitly-generated special method, is called:

```cpp
Container::Container(std::string strName, std::string strType, Geometry geometry)
  /*: stdstrContainerName()
    , stdstrPluginType()
    , Geom()*/                    // default-constructors implicitly called as member-initialisation    
{
    stdstrContainerName = stdstrContainerName;
    stdstrPluginType = stdstrPluginType;
    Geom = geometry;              // copy-assignment, i.e. operator= (Geometry const&)  
}
```

To override the default behaviour, use [member initialisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) explicitly:

```cpp
Container::Container(std::string strName, std::string strType, Geometry geometry)
    : stdstrContainerName(strName)
    , stdstrPluginType(strType)
    , Geom(geometry)            // copy-constructor, i.e. Geometry(Geometry const&)    
{
}
```

This should yield constructor 3, as the copy-constructor is now called.

[***Demo***](https://ideone.com/ohRDTD)

---

On switching over to member initialisation, you may have noticed that constructor 3 is called twice. Again, this is due to the constructor of Container taking its `geometry` parameter *by value*, creating a new object via copy-constructing. To prevent a copy from being made and make the constructor more efficient, we can pass `geometry` by reference. In addition, we can const-ify the parameter to guarantee that the reference isn't modified in the constructor.

Thus the constructor of `Container` can be changed to:

```cpp
Container(const std::string &strName, const std::string &strType, const Geometry &geometry);
```

Comment: As answered, in the first case the internal geometry object is already created by the time you reach the assignment line. So essentially the Geometry object is being constructed using no args. It is preferred to use initialization lists in case of such cases, you can read-up more about it [here](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html)

Comment: In the second block of code the comment is a bit misleading because you call the constructor explicitly there's no implicit thing happening. Besides that I agree with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `Container`'s constructor:

```
Container::Container(std::string strName, std::string strType, Geometry geometry)
{
    stdstrContainerName = stdstrContainerName;
    stdstrPluginType = stdstrPluginType;
    Geom = geometry;
}
```

doesn't have any explicit initialization of the `Geom` field. It is first default initialized hence the default constructor call and then you assign it the `geometry` argument.

To achive what you want, you need to define `Container`'s constructor this way:

```
Container::Container(std::string strName, std::string strType, Geometry geometry)
: Geom(geometry)
{
    stdstrContainerName = strName;
    stdstrPluginType = strType;
}
```

Notice the `: Geom(geometry)` part. This is where the constructor of `Geom` is called and if you don't put something like that in your constructor then the default one is called.

Also, I'm almost certain that you have a bug in your constructor. It probably should be `stdstrContainerName = strName;` and not `stdstrContainerName = stdstrContainerName;`. The same applies to `stdstrPluginType`.

One more thing, this is not a bug and is technically correct but passing objects of types like `std::string` or `Geometry` (that is objects which might be 'heavy') might be decrease performance so why don't you pass them by reference? But that's not a bug (at least not in the piece of code you posted) and isn't directly related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor #1 is called for the `Geometry geometry` argument passed by value to the constructor of `Container`. Because you are passing it by value, it is recreated on the stack of the constructor of `Container`. Change it to `const Geometry& geometry`.

Comment: How can i change it to be passed for the appropriate constructor ?

Comment: Passing by reference is a good suggestion but it doesn't solve the problem in the question and has actually nothing to do with calling the default constructor. For details see my answer to the question or the answer of TrebledJ.